# Change selection of radio group whenever a radio button is clicked

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have a custom radio group with two radio buttons inside it, what I want is to change its selection even if the user clicks on a checked radio button.

for now this is how it works:

[image]

as you see, if (off) is checked and I click on it, nothing happens.. I want it to change selection to (on).

I tried to use OnClickListener like this:

```
final RadioButton btn_on = view.findViewById(R.id.on);
    final RadioButton btn_off = view.findViewById(R.id.off);

    final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if(radio_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==R.id.on)
                {
                    radio_group.check(R.id.off);
                }

                if(radio_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==R.id.off)
                {
                    radio_group.check(R.id.on);
                }

        }
    };

    btn_on.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_off.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

but it won't work.. is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
boolean fromClickListener = false;
boolean fromCheckedChange = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RadioGroup radio_group = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    final RadioButton btn_on = findViewById(R.id.on);
    final RadioButton btn_off = findViewById(R.id.off);

    radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (fromClickListener)
                return;

            fromCheckedChange = true;
        }
    });


    final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fromCheckedChange) {
                fromCheckedChange = false;
                return;
            }

            boolean clickedOn = (((RadioButton) v) == btn_on);

            fromClickListener = true;
            btn_on.setChecked(!clickedOn);
            btn_off.setChecked(clickedOn);
            fromClickListener = false;
        }
    };

    btn_on.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_off.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you ! 
but I had a problem with the code inside the OnCheckedChangeListener , wasn't firing when it was changed by the click, so I had to duplicate the code in both listeners, not sure if it's the ideal way but it worked for me.
Thanks A lot.